# Vectorized looping pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, vectorization

Hi I need to create a column with values 1 or 0 based on certain conditions. My dataframe is enormous, so a general for loop or even apply are extremely slow. I want to used Pandas or even more preferably Numpy vectorization. Below is a sample of the data and my code that does not work:

```
election_year     D_president

1992                 0
1992                 0
1996                 0
1996                 0
2000                 0
2004                 0
2008                 0
2012                 0
```

```
test_df['D_president'] = 0
election_year = test_df['election_year']
test_df['D_president'] = test_df.loc[((election_year == 1992) | 
(election_year == 1996) | 
(election_year == 2008)| 
(election_year == 2012)), 'D_president'] = 1
```

So basically I need to get a value of 1 in a column 'D_president' for these certain years. However, when I execute this code I get all 1 even for 2000 and 2004. Can't understand what's wrong. 
Also how could I transform this into a Numpy vectorization with .values?

Comment: It looks like you're having two "=" assignments on the same row. 
Try removing the leftmost one test_df['D_president']

Also, for the test, you can replace it with election_year.isin([1992, 1996, 2008, 2012]))

Comment: @ilmarinen thank you! works!! want to add an answer? I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're having two "=" assignments on the same row. Try removing the leftmost one test_df['D_president'] Also, for the test, you can replace it with election_year.isin([1992, 1996, 2008, 2012]))